# How to use preprocessor macro used in third party framework

Tags: ios, ios-frameworks

I'm developing an SDK for iOS and I use a preprocessor macro in order to change the behaviour of my code, for example:

```
#ifdef Home
    NSLog(@"I'm at home");
#endif
```

Now I built a Framework to deliver my SDK but if I try to import it in a test app that code is never executed. I try to add the same preprocessor macro to the app targer without success.

Please can you tell me how to setup preprocessor macro defined inside a 3rd party Framework?

Thanks
Giulio

Comment: This is a very good question, albeit an apparently difficult one and rarely encountered. I am also stuck on this and would love to know if you found a workaround !

Comment: the #debug macro also not working in swift framework.                               #if DEBUG                                                                          NSLog(@"deubg")                                                                                    #else
 NSLog(@"relese");
 #endif

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
#define Home
```

To this macro will be able to execute

```
#ifdef Home
NSLog(@"I'm at home");
#endif
```

Comment: I defined Home in "my target -> Build Settings -> Preprocessor Macro". The problem is when I build framework and I try to include it in another app. What I have to change to execute this NSLog?

Comment: Could you add '#define Home' to some .h file from your Framework?

Comment: Uhmm...please explain better, I don't understand what you mean. I used that macros in order to enable/disable a feature of my SDK. A developer can choose to enable it or to keep disable. I think it was enough that developer could add the same macros to its preprocessor to enable it but it's not so simple. Thanks

Comment: Each framework has header files to other developers can have access to functions framework. Usually framework has main .h file, which contains other .h files of this framework. You can add definition to this .h file. Open some system framework and you will see headers folder

Comment: Yes, but if I add this definition to my main .h file and then I distribute the framework, how does the developer can choose if enable or not the feature? There must be something that add developers to their project.

Comment: Why do you want to use preprocessor macro? You can replace everything your #ifdef to if([KeepingFeatureClass featureEnabled]), and set(save to NSUSerDefaults some flag) this feature in one of your framework functions

Comment: Because if developer want to enable this feature, he has to import other frameworks. With preprocessor macro I created two different target in xcode that allow me to build two different Framework, one for developer that doesn't want extra feature and one for others. But probably it's not the correct way to achieve this.

Comment: @Giulio, did you find a way to do this ? I am struggling on the *exact* same thing as you, and came to the *exact* same conclusion as you, but now I don't know what to do ! I really don't want to include that library in mine for every user...

Comment: Samething I am also looking for. I also stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but may be you can think of cocoapods for your dependencies inside your framework. If it is possible, create a prefix header. Inside your podspec, you can identify the subspecs(the dependencies that the end developer who is using your framework must mention - who want to enable or disable) and you can define the "prefix_header_contents" to add a macro.

Say for example, if the end-developer want to enable a feature of "AFNetworking" provided by your framework, the developer should add your framework using his pod file like

pod 'YourFrameworkPod', :subspecs => ["AFNetworking"]

This will add your framework as well as AFNetworking to the developer's project.

You must define your podspec like

```
s.subspec 'AFNetworking' do |af|
    af.prefix_header_contents = '#define AF_EXISTS'
    af.source_files = 'YourPod/Classes/**/*'
    af.dependency 'AFNetworking'
end
```

So you can do your AFNetworking related codes inside

```
 #ifdef AF_EXISTS
    Your stuff!
 #endif
```